# Migrating domain by .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need some help with migrating from one domain to another. There's 2 issues to this problem...

ISSUE 1:
Right now the domain1 has links like http://www.domain1.com/archives/this-is-an-article/

I need to 301 redirect in htaccess to http://domain2.com/this-is-an-article/

So the domains change and there's an additional /archives/ in there that needs to be cut off.

ISSUE 2:
I have a subdomain on domain1 that needs to be 301 redirect to just the home page of domain2.  example: http://subdomain.domain1.com/hello-there/ should 301 redirect to http://domain2.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^archives/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```